Is setting INTRA_PARALLEL, MAX_QUERYDEGREE, DFT_DEGREE good?
Our custumer has migrated their database to a new system and we feel that the performance of SQLs could be better. We are wondering if setting INTRA_PARALLEL (currently NO) and/or MAX_QUERYDEGREE (currently ANY), DFT_DEGREE (currently 1) could boost the performance.
What do you think? What are experiences of others? When is setting those parameters to other that the default values smart?
I know it is not very specific question, but I'd still like to get some feedback from tohers that have done this.

This is not a programming question, It is a DBA question concerning configuration.  Better suited to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/db2?tab=Active   .  "we feel that the performance of SQL could be better"  is meaningless without detailed context and more facts.

the right answer is: it depend of you use cas, is it transactional or analytic need. usually parallism in a transactional envrionnement is use less and it might even be slower then no transactional
